# .htaccess 301 Redirect that Works for http and https cases, .com and localhost

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https, local, permanent

I need to do a 301 redirect on a single page. If I just wanted it to work from www.example.com, I would have:

```
redirect 301 /urisegment1/urisegment2/urisegment3 http://www.example.com/urisegment1/urisegment2/NEWURISEGMENT3
```

The problem is, users may access http://www.example.com/urisegment1/urisegment2/urisegment3  or sometimes https://www.example.com/urisegment1/urisegment2/urisegment3/ if they have been logged in and access SSL-protected pages. Also I have the site set up locally so I can access it through http://www.example.local/urisegment1/urisegment2/urisegment3

How can I get this to work for all cases?

---

(That's the end of the question, my current .htaccess file below in case it is relevant. Note it's mostly not my own work, it is drawn from various sources).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /


#Removes trailing slashes (prevents SEO duplicate content issues)
#RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
#RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

#forces www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]

#force homepage to http from https
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com$ 
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on 
RewriteRule ^$ http://www.example.com/ [R=301,L]

#If a controller can't be found - then issue a 404 error from PHP
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html

#Removes access to the system folder by users.
#Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
#previously this would not have been possible.
#'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^sys.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
# such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
# request to index.php. The first condition allows access to assets, css, js and the robots file
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|assets|css|js|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]


RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*/index.php
RewriteRule ^(.*)index.php$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,L]

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
# Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
# previously this would not have been possible.
# 'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]


</IfModule>


<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>

# Without mod_rewrite, route 404's to the front controller
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php

</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tried the following rule

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !newvalue/?$
RewriteRule ^(.*)/[^/]+/?$ /$1/newvalue [L,R=301]
```

which should keep everything but the last URI segment, so it should work with http(s) and different domains.

You have to update the *newvalue* in both lines to avoid endless redirects.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. However let's say my 'urisegment3' was something like 'example-directory-about-computers' and my new 'urisegment3' was 'computer-directory', how would the rewrite rule you posted redirect from old to new? 'newvalue' is on both lines? I tried it without success unfortunately